# FTP Shell Script Not Working With Cronjob

Tags: linux, shell, ftp, cron

Ok, So I am trying to ftp some recording files to a remote server for backup every night. It gets the files created today and transfers them. It works just fine, but only if I run it manually. The cronjob doesn't run it.

Here is current script:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch -t $(date +"%Y%m%d0000") /tmp/$$

NOW=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
HOST='remote_server'  
USER='ftp_user'             
PASS='ftp_password'          

#create directory with date as the name, copy recordings.php for interface
ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASS
mkdir /recordings/$NOW
cd /recordings/$NOW
put recordings.php
bye
EOF

find  -name '*.mp3' -newer /tmp/$$ |
while read FILE
do
ftp -in $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASS
cd /recordings/$NOW
put $FILE
bye
EOF

done

rm -f /tmp/$$
```

Then I have it set in crontab like this, so it runs every night at 11pm:

```
* 21 * * * /var/spool/asterisk/monitorDONE/MP3/recording_script.sh
```

Any help is greatly appreciated guys. I understand this might not be the best way to do this, it's just the first way I came across that worked for me, so I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Does the cronjob not run at all or not run successfully?

Comment: The method appears alright. Is record_script.sh executable? Do a chmod 755 recording_script.sh on it and run it through cron again. Check the cron log file to see the output of the job. Cron log might be under /var/log or var/log/syslog

Comment: this is what the log says when the cron tried to run the script: `Sep  8 21:04:01 vici crond[16478]: (root) CMD (/var/spool/asterisk/monitorDONE/MP3/recording_script.sh)
Sep  8 21:04:01 vici crond[16477]: (root) NULL security context for user, but SELinux in permissive mode, continuing ()
`

Comment: So the script runs when it's supposed to. It creates the new directory for the files, it just doesn't copy any of the files.

Comment: Is the find statement without a path part intentional? `find` might be executed somewhere else when executing from a cronjob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check your PATH variable and add /usr/local/bin to it, if for example `ftp` is installed there.

Also, adding

```
... > /tmp/script.log 2>&1
```

will provide more information on why the cronjob fails (or at least does not do anything.

Try prefixing your cronjob command with

```
bash -x ...
```

to show every shell statement as it is being executed.

Complete crontab line:

```
* 21 * * * bash -x /var/spool/asterisk/monitorDONE/MP3/recording_script.sh >/tmp/rs_log 2>&1
```

Hope this helps for debugging your problem.

Comment: Awesome. Using that debugging, I was able to figure out my issue. Before the find statement and the while loop, I had to cd to the folder I was searching for (`/var/spool/asterisk/monitorDONE/MP3/`) and then it ran great. Thanks everyone.